# Is there a cross language logger

Tags: python, java, logs, r

I want to able to run a single logger and post to it from different languages. Is there a single logger out there that will work with java python and r?

Comment: Are you ok with a C interface? Because that's what you are likely to get

Comment: Im open. Tell me more...